# Mysql connection not working with Windows Firewall on

Tags: mysql, windows-7, firewall

Using Windows 7 Pro,  Mysql server 5.7 installed on local pc.

It was working till the pc moved to another private network. When I open Mysql Workbench and click the only connection I have, it doesn't ask for any password, when it should, it did before. When I disable Windows Firewall all its fine, I tried to add Indbound and Outbound exeptions to 3306 port TCP, in Private and Domain mode to the Windows Firewall, but when I close the windows the rules disappear, the name is codified, and other rules just doesn't add.

mysqld.exe is the only service of mysqlserver present in inbound and outbound  rules.

**Edit:**

Modifying the connection in the workbench from 'localhost' to  'serverIP' (wich is the same host) works. But doesn't work for other programs which need connection too. Any suggestion?

Comment: From an article :  http://superuser.com/questions/1096120/windows-firewall-rules-keep-reverting-after-refresh it's look like that some software have conflict with rules creation see post from Ventzy Kunev.

Do you have ''TunnelBear'' running on your computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, it was another firewall that was giving issues with Windows services and other stuff. I had to add rules in Control Panel/Windows Firewall/Advanced settings/Inbound rules and add new rule for connections over port 3306

Comment: Here is a link on how to add an exception to Windows Firewall Defender https://stackoverflow.com/a/55307776/5411817

Comment: I tried a lot of way to fix this issue. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 and Windows 10:
Allow access through windows firewall for program C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\mysql\bin\mysql and ...\mysqld
Firewall advanced settings and make a new inbound rule for tcp port 3306. 
Install the appropriate C++ for 2010, mine was (x86)